# OSError : errno 22, Invalid Argument; when trying to use to_json

Tags: python, json

I made a little python script to ingest some data, do some stuff with it and write the result to a json.
All of it works fine until the writing to json part.
The result of all the transforming is a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
 val1           val2        val3        val4        val5
'somestring'    somefloat   somefloat   somefloat   'somestring'
```

It contains about 18mil lines like this. The string in val5 can contain spaces and things like / and ().
I can't show any of the real data or most of the code for sensitivity reasons.

The code I use to try and make it into JSON is:

```
df.to_json("/Users/user/Documents/file.json", orient = "records")
```

This line has worked before on other data, and I tried it on a random dataset and it worked.

I can also save this data to CSV, no problems there.

```
df.to_csv("/Users/user/Documents/file.csv")
```

Oh and here is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-40-7b582d16ec2c>", line 2, in <module>
file.to_json("/Users/user/Documents/file.json", orient = 
"records")

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", 
line 1891, in to_json
index=index)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/json.py", 
line 66, in to_json
fh.write(s)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I know it's not much to go on, and if you can't help because of it I understand. But I am at the end of my wits, so I thought I at least try, maybe one of you has some idea.

Comment: "_I can't show any of the real data or most of the code for sensitivity reasons._" - the best approach is to produce a simplified scenario that produces the same error. You may even figure out what's going wrong while doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been trying but haven't succeeded yet. But I'll keep at it :)

Comment: `errno 22` is `EINVAL` ("_Invalid argument_" as shown), implying that either the _file handle_ or one of the other arguments (e.g: `size` / `nmemb`) is invalid when `write()` is called... Is the file open for a long time? Has it been deleted in the meantime? Have you closed it? Is the disk full? You mentioned 18 million lines - how long is `s`?

Comment: No to: deleted, open for a long time, closed it and full disk. It's about 1 gig in size, 18 mil lines but only 5 columns. I've worked with 10gig files before so I doubt the size is an issue here. I'll take a look at nmemb, thanks :)

Comment: (`nmemb` is at the C-level, so under python's exposed `f.write()` API - it would only be relevant if `s` is _really_ long > ~2 GB)